# Rails OAUTH2.CLIENT_ERROR.HEADING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to access polar accesslink and provided authorization url is https://flow.polar.com/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&scope={SCOPE}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&state={STATE}

client_id is correct. I am using oauth2 gem

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, :site => authorize_url)

@url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/')
```

this is giving me some template in terminal. but the process is to redirect to the url, user will authorize the login, it will redirect back to the redirect_ur.

Comment: OAUTH2.CLIENT_ERROR.HEADING
this is also showing this error after redirecting to polar flow

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You may need to ensure the `redirect_uri` you specify in the URL matches the `Authorization callback domain` in your app's settings. Check at https://admin.polaraccesslink.com

If these do not match, that error is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems okay except one thing, The targeted api do not accept multiple request from same user account of that website. For example, Polar user can authorize his/her account only once. That was the problem I have found.